# Solution for backing up to multiple destinations

Tags: backup

I want to backup one or several directories to multiple destinations. For example, I want to put backups on 2 different HDD of a backup server or put one copy of backup on a backup server and another on a backup client.

**Requirements**: It should be free software with a server for linux and a client for windows and linux. Client only for linux is not so suitable, but it would be great too.

Now it is implemented using *rsync + tar*. But it isn't good because of decentralization and less control.

I tried *Bacula*, but the only possible way of backing up to multiple directories is creation of multiple tasks. And there is no possibility to put backup on the client.

Also I tried *Amanda*. I can use RAIT for copying to multiple directories, but this directories on the backup server.

A good example of backing up to multiple directories is *Cobian Backup*. But first of all it isn't client-server solution. And it is solely for windows.

So it is my problem and I need help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1) You may just fire up just 2 rsyncs to server and client backup, but you may find this approach IO expensive on source depending your situation

2) Wild guess: RAID1 the 2 HDDs

3) More sophisticated: Consider using mirror mounts, where backing up to a specific destination the filesystem takes care of duplicating

Comment: 1) I had problem with rsync, when remote server hanged because of IO. So I want to avoid using rsync.

2) If something will go wrong on RAID1, for example, deletion of backups, it will be replicated on all HDDs.

3) Do you mean something like GlusterFS? Is the situation like with RAID possible?

Destinations should be independent.